# Validation for accepting numbers and special characters using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written a validation for accepting numbers and special characters but it is accepting only numbers while validating not accepting special characters.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#law_degree_academic_years").keypress(function (e) {
 if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
   $("#errmsg").html("Digits Only").show().fadeOut("slow");
           return false;
}
 });
});

<div class="form-group"> 
                                    <label for="law_degree_academic_years" class="col-sm-2 control-label">41. Law Degree Academic Years</label> 
                                    <div class="col-sm-9"> 
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $oppointArr['law_degree_academic_years'];?>" name="law_degree_academic_years" id="law_degree_academic_years" placeholder="Ex:2017-2020" minlegth="9" maxlength="9" required> 
                                    </div> 
                                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method

```
function Validate() {
        var isValid = false;
        var regex = /^[0-9-+()]*$/;
        isValid = regex.test(document.getElementById("TextBox1").value);
        return isValid;
}
```

Comment: It is accepting alphabets it should not accept alphabets only numbers and special characters should be accepted

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution to your issue could be the HTML5 pattern attribute for input elements.

```
<input name="bla" type="text" pattern="[0-9-+()]*" placeholder="add something" required>
```

The pattern attribute executes a validation with the given regular expression and sets the status of the input element to valid or invalid. You do not need javascript for the simple purpose of testing.

More information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation

Comment: If i add numbers also it is not accepting

Comment: The above shown regex is a simple example for using the pattern attribute. You can adjust the regular expression by yourself. Anyway ...you seem to be new to Stack Overflow. Keep in mind, that Stack Overflow is not a service to solve your issues. It is only to show you the right way. Because I 'm a kind dude: Add a `*` to the pattern for zero or more repetitions. `[0-9-+()]*`. You should urgently acquire some basic knowledge of RegEx.